# How to exclude airlines by marketing code in Bargain Finder Max

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to exclude some airlines when sending sabre RQ, I tried adding this to my payload:

```
{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
        ...
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "IntelliSellTransaction": {
                "RequestType": {
                    "Name": "200ITINS"
                },
                "CompressResponse": {
                    "Value": true
                }
            },
            "AlternatePCC": {
                "PseudoCityCode": "SOME CODE IN HERE",
                "TravelPreferences": {
                    "TPA_Extensions": {
                        "ExcludeAlliancePref": [
                            {
                                "Code": "AA"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "VendorPref": []
                }
            }
        },
        "AvailableFlightsOnly": true,
        "Target": "Production",
        "Version": "4.4.0"
    },
}
```

I'm receiving:

```
"message": "27131",
    "additionalMessages": [
        {
            "type": "MAIN",
            "errorCode": "PARSER",
            "message": "JSON_ADAPTER returned an error"
        },
```

Not pretty sure what is wrong perhaps my city code?